# labs() command to set legend title ignored by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using the following code but my command labs(fill = "Class") that should set the legend title to be "Class" is ignored:

```
    ggplot(data_Test, aes(x = predictions_plain, fill = as.factor(income_Class), 
color = as.factor(income_Class))) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity",alpha = 0.4) + 
guides(color = FALSE)
      geom_density (alpha = 0.5)+ 
     labs(title = "Predicted Probabilities per Class in the Test Dataset", 
      x = "Predicted Probability of being in Class1", y = "Count") + 
      labs(fill = "Class")
```

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are there two separate `labs()` calls? Have you tried moving `fill = "Class"` into the same call as your other titles?

Comment: Also I think you are missing a `+` after `guides(color = FALSE)`. That means all the subsequent commands won't be applied to the plot.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think the 2 `labs()` and other syntax errors is your issue.

```
ggplot(data_Test, aes(x = predictions_plain)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill = as.factor(income_Class)),
                 position = "identity", alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5, aes(color = as.factor(income_Class))) + 
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Predicted Probabilities per Class in the Test Dataset", 
       x = "Predicted Probability of being in Class1",
       y = "Count",
       fill = "Class")
```

And here's another way...

```
ggplot(data_Test, aes(x = predictions_plain)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill = as.factor(income_Class)),
                 position = "identity", alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5, aes(color = as.factor(income_Class))) + 
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Predicted Probabilities per Class in the Test Dataset", 
       x = "Predicted Probability of being in Class1",
       y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Class")
```

Comment: `?labs` suggests that it is an OK way to set legend titles, I've always done it that way. It says: "You can also set axis and legend labels in the individual scales (using the first argument, the name. I recommend doing that *if you're changing other scale options.*"

Comment: Yes, you're correct, `labs(fill="Class")` should work, if the rest of the syntax is correct. I've always done it the other way :)